# Keeping TOC layers unchecked on first load in ArcGIS JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, table-of-contents

I am new to ArcGIS and it's API.
I am using NLiu's TOC widget for displaying the layers. It is working perfectly, however, I wanted to keep all layers unchecked when it is loading on the browser (for performance reason).

I used the visible property of dynamic layer as:

```
var layer= new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(mapService,{"visible": false});
```

This hides the layer, but when I am expanding its childs, all of them are selected (checked), when I am clicking to uncheck one, the rest others are displaying back.

So, what I want, to keep all its child nodes un-selected, when I am checking a single checkbox, so it should display its relevant data on the map.

I tried to find a way on its javascript files but not succeed.

Comment: Which version of the API are you using? Can you post a link to the TOC code you're using? Can you post a simplified example demo (maybe using jsbin.com or similar)?